# Why does ARC not work correctly when directly assigning an object to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have these two objects

```
//Header file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Object2;

@interface Object1 : NSObject
@property Object2 *child;

@end

@interface Object2 : NSObject

@property (weak) Object1 *parent;

@end

// Implementation File
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation Object1

-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"deallocating parent");
}

@end

@implementation Object2

-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"deallocating child");
}

@end
```

When I set the child and parent relationships without introducing a new variable for the child,

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Object1 *p2 = [[Object1 alloc]init];
        p2.child = [[Object2 alloc]init];

        p2.child.parent = p2;

        NSLog(@"Setting p1 to nil");
        p2=nil;
        NSLog(@"Done");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The child doesn't seem to get deallocated before "Done" is printed.

But if I use an intermediate variable to hold the child object, deallocation seems to happen fine.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    Object1 *p1 = [[Object1 alloc]init];
    Object2 *c1 = [[Object2 alloc]init];
    p1.child = c1;

    c1.parent = p1;
    c1 = nil;

    NSLog(@"Setting p1 to nil");
    p1=nil;
    NSLog(@"Done");


}
```

I am curious as to why this happens.

Comment: Just to clarify, everything is properly deallocated in both cases, correct? It's a question of timing between the two, correct?

Comment: No, it gets deallocated when the program ends, i guess. I tried adding a breakpoint on the last NSLog, and the dealloc method for the child wasn't called till then.

Comment: I think that if you went on to do other work outside that autorelease pool, that Object2 would get deallocated when the pool closes. In any case, I would still regard the behavior as you described as correct, if somewhat non-intuitive.

Comment: Deallocation isn't guaranteed to happen immediately. Close the autorelease pool before your log to get the behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

`p2.child = [[Object2 alloc]init];`

creates a "retain/autoreleased" object and calls a setter that will then retain that object, so the object will be de-allocated at the closure of the autorelease pool. The compiler is not smart enough to optimize out the autorelease.

Somehow, ARC compiles your code as the equivalent of MRR:

`p2.child = [[[Object2 alloc]init] autorelease];`

When you write:

`Object2 *c1 = [[Object2 alloc]init];`

The compiler is smart enough to optimize out the autorelease and make it a simple release when you call `c1 = nil`.

ARC compiles your code as the equivalent of MRR:

`Object2 *c1 = [[Object2 alloc]init];
...
[c1 release];
c1 = nil;`

Just as a side note, the object is always correctly de-allocated, it's just deallocated at the end `@autoreleasepool`:

`2014-07-11 13:18:03.233 TestWeak[48241:303] Setting p1 to nil
2014-07-11 13:18:03.235 TestWeak[48241:303] deallocating parent
2014-07-11 13:18:03.235 TestWeak[48241:303] Done
2014-07-11 13:18:03.236 TestWeak[48241:303] deallocating child`

Comment: `init` methods return a (+1) retained object, not an autoreleased object.

Comment: 1) `-init` does not change retain count (`+alloc` does, somehow) 2) we are talking about ARC here which adds retain/release/autorelease as it believes fits. Updating my answer to make it more

Comment: This simply isn't true. `p2.child = [[Object2 alloc]init];` does not create a retained/autoreleased object. It returns a +1 retained object as @MartinR indicates. ARC and MRC are identical in that line of code. You can see this in the Assembly output. It just calls `+alloc`, `-init`, and `-setChild:`. The extra retain/autorelease happens in the call to `-child`, not the call to `-init`.

Comment: It's not even an ARC issue. You'd see the same behavior in MRC as long as `child` is atomic.

Comment: Indeed, you are right here. In the end, the object is autoreleased but not for these reasons.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of things going on here, and it's a pretty good example to explore. The first thing to realize is that the dealloc isn't happening at the end of the program. It's happening at the end of the autorelease pool (as Julien notes). ObjC doesn't run `dealloc` at program termination. You'd see this if you moved the "Done" line outside the autoreleasepool. The second big thing to understand is that this has nothing to do with ARC. The behavior would be the same with MRC.

So why the difference with an intermediate? Well, you need to think about what this line means:

```
p2.child.parent = p2;
```

That's really:

```
[[p2 child] setParent:p2];
```

And that's equivalent to:

```
id temp = [p2 child];
[temp setParent:p2];
```

That call to `[p2 child]` never happens in your other example (it calls `[p2 setChild:]`, which is completely different).

You've used the default property settings for `child`. The default settings include `atomic`. That means that our getter looks something like:

```
- (Object2 *)child {
  return [[_child retain] autorelease];
}
```

(It's a little more complicated, because it also synchronizes with the setter, but that doesn't matter to this discussion.)

So now we have an autoreleased `temp` hanging around that will be cleaned up at the end of the autorelease pool. If you added `(nonatomic)` to your property definition, you'll see that the behavior matches your expectation.

Your other example never makes that call to `[p2 child]`, so it doesn't put an extra retain/autorelease on it, and so it is deallocated sooner.

A lesson here is that in most cases `nonatomic` is preferred. It was a little surprising that `atomic` was made the default, and many Cocoa devs use `nonatomic` almost exclusively (most Apple example code does too). The idea of the extra retain/autorelease is that it provides some protection in multi-threaded code (without it, your local variable could deallocate before you were done with it). In practice, there are usually better ways to go about this than `atomic` (and `atomic` doesn't give you actual thread safety by itself). That said, it is not a problem to use `atomic` properties, and the code above has no errors; it just requires a little more memory for a little longer.

If you're curious about such things, I always recommend taking a look at the Assembly output. It can be a little hard to read, but you can usually learn a lot about what the compiler is choosing to do. In the Assistant pane, just select "Assembly" (from the same menu that has "Counterparts").